# Testing for transformation-errors in different signals

Tags: time-series, cross-correlation

Let's suppose I have two signals, or time series (for this matter).

The first time series (let's call it "A"), is a collection of measurements made every 15 minutes.

| Time | Value |
| --- | --- |
| 08h00 | 2.6 |
| 08h15 | 2.4 |
| 08h30 | 2.6 |
| 08h45 | 3 |
| 09h00 | 2.5 |

The time series "B", is a collection of measurements of the same variable, but done every hour.

| Time | Value |
| --- | --- |
| 08h00 | 2.5 |
| 09h00 | 2.5 |

I won't go into specifics here, but assume that there's a rule to transform "A" into the "B" scale by taking the mean of the 4 values associated with every hour. So for example, transforming A would result in:

| Time | Value |
| --- | --- |
| 08h00 | (2.6 + 2.4 + 2.6 + 3) / 4 |
| 09h00 | 2.5 |

"A", when transformed, is supposed to be approximately equal to "B", which is the "correct" signal.

The problem:
What if for some technical issue, whatever records the time that goes into "A" is broken, and now the time column is shifted by +- 15 min. If that happens, the transformation will be different, because the values were shifted, right? So how could one go about detecting this time shift?

Using tools like cross correlation won't work, because you don't have "B" in the 15-minutes scale.

Comment: Could you clarify what is actually observed?  A?  B?  Both? The "broken" A?  Something else?

Comment: Sure! A and B are measurements of the same variable (say, temperature!) done by different equipments, in different frequencies (one is every 15 min, the other is hourly). A and B are supposed to be more or less the same when A is transformed into the B scale.

Comment: Both are observed. You have acess to the B values and the A values (transformed or not). The thing is, when you transform a time-shifted A, you can identify small irregularities in amplitude when compared to B. I'll try to post a plot of this.

Comment: If both are observed, it's difficult to discern a question here.  Are you trying to say B and *either* A or its time-shifted version are observed (you don't know which) and you would like to determine which of those two possibilities is likelier?

Comment: Both are observed. I'm trying to figure out wether or not A was time-shifted. If it was, how much was the shift? 15 min? 30 min? So the question remains: how can you detect a time shift in A with respect to B, considering that A is only comparable to B after applying the transformation.

Comment: I think I follow.  But your final statement about cross-correlation not working is baffling, because the cross-correlation gives the obvious, simple solution: examine the cross-correlation between $B$ and each of the (two or three or however many) shifted, averaged versions of $A$ and pick the one with the largest value.

Comment: That makes sense. I'll try it out. Thank you for your thoughts and time.